# How can I pass a parameter to callback function which is inside map function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am a new learner of JS, there is a function like this

```
const generateNum = (array, key) => {
    return array.map(i => parseFloat(i.key));
}
```

however, in this fn, key is declared but never used, how can I pass this parameter to the inside of map fn.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const generateNum = (array, key) => {
  return array.map(i => parseFloat(i[key]));
}
```

A simple example for explanation.

```js
let person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
};

let key = 'name';

person.key; // does not exist (only name and age is inside person object) so it would be undefined
person[key]; // exists because it means person.name actually
```

Comment: Amazing !!!!! It worked!!!! Could you please explain what happen here, why this work? Any reference or doc  I can read? Realy realy appreciate

Comment: Yes I didn't explain, sorry :/ . The "key" is a variable. If this variable has the value 'name' for example then it tries to get the i.name.

Answer (score 4):

By doing `i.key` you are trying to access key property of the `i` object. Since you are passing `key` as a parameter to `generateNum` function you can use `key` as a variable inside the function body.

```
const generateNum = (array, key) => {
  return array.map(i => parseFloat(i[key]));
}
```

Comment: That is so cool !!!!!!!! Thank you for your explanation,